# Commom Table Expression Errors

Tags: t-sql

I have a requirement to rewrite some of our simple select statement queries using a CTE. And I have had no problems doing so until I encountered one like the query below:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO
DECLARE @TotalRows INT 
SELECT @TotalRows = COUNT(CustomerID)
FROM Sales.Customer
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader);

SELECT @TotalRows AS 'T'
```

And I rewrote it like the one below but I am getting error.

```
DECLARE @TotalRows INT 
;WITH TotalRows
(
SELECT @TotalRows = COUNT(CustomerID)
FROM Sales.Customer
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader))
SELECT * FROM TotalRows
```

How do I make this work using a CTE?

Comment: Why do you have to create CTE's where it makes no sense?

Comment: Like I explained, it's a requirement and it's only because it's part of a major Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use a CTE (i don't see the added value), this should work:

```
DECLARE @TotalRows INT; 

WITH TotalRows 
     AS (SELECT C.* 
         FROM   Sales.Customer C
         WHERE  CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID 
                               FROM   Sales.Salesorderheader)) 
SELECT @TotalRows = Count(CustomerID) 
FROM   TotalRows
```

Comment: Hello Tim, thank you. But I got the following erro:
    Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
    The column prefix 'C' does not match with a table name or      alias name used in the query.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'TotalRows'.

Comment: @dLight: that was just the (missing) table alias, i've edited the answer.